# mininet call unknown host while pinging using ping6

Tags: ipv6, sdn, mininet

I use mininet and odl,but in mininet ,when I use ping6 like below:

```
mininet>h1 ping6 h2 
mininet>unknown host
```

I changed odl to Ryu.It is same.
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

IPv6 on Mininet does not have host name lookup facility. instead if you use ipv6 address like

```
#h1 ping6 <IPv6_address_of_h2>
```

then you will get the replies.